# Accept cookies with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, popup

I am aware that similar questions have been asked numerous times, but I have tried everything to no avail.

I am scrapping [this website](https://www.loterie.lu/content/portal/fr/playnow/lotto/results.html)

The following used to work:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="queryDateMonth"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="queryDateMonth"]'))).send_keys(month)
```

Until they introduced a Cookiebot popup.

From that moment onwards, sometimes, but not always I receive an error according to which the section I need to click has been obscured by the cookies popup.

I have tried to include code to always accept the cookies:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]'))).click()
```

But then I am told that selenium cannot scroll down to the button. However, there is no need to scroll down, the pop up is always visible. I have tried maximising the window, just in case.

I checked if it was an alert and tried to focus on it prior to clicking:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.alert_is_present())
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

But this does not work. I don't think it is an alert.

Then I saw there is an iframe, even though I am not sure if it is the relevant one:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '/html/body/iframe[2]')))
```

But this does not work either.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like 

iframe = driver.find_element(By.ID, "iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

Comment: Thanks @CatMai, but iframe is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First we accept all the cookies:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialog"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]'))).click()
```

And then we can proceed with the usual stuff:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="queryDateMonth"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="queryDateMonth"]'))).send_keys(month)
```